# Fetch Case Feed from Case in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to fetch case feed from case in soql, I have tried with below but it throws out the error: Didn't understand relationship 'casefeeds' in FROM part of query call.`

```
Select Id, CaseNumber, CreatedDate,(select id,parentid from casefeeds) From Case Where Status ='Pending Customer'
```

I can see that case feed with this query but i need to fetch from case object

```
Select id,parentid from casefeed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship name is `FEEDS` so the following query should work.

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, CreatedDate,(SELECT Id,ParentId FROM Feeds) FROM Case
```

If you want to view the relationships, you can use this code.

```
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> relations = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Case').getDescribe().getChildRelationships();

System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(relations));
```